# Python app run using browser

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

I would like to run my python application locally in any web browser. I am using PyCharm IDE for my Python apps but when i run app from IDE, its not running in browser. How it can solve?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you should run your code using server. there are many available. for example:

[a link](http://docs.python.org/3/library/wsgiref.html?highlight=simple%20server#wsgiref.simple_server.make_server)

your code will be triggered through demo_app in example from link above.